# How to read object URI json file

Tags: reactjs, api

I am able to read this JSON file but I am not able to read object URI JSON file. How can I use Object URI JSON File?

And this is the way I tried to read Uri json object

```
  componentDidMount(){
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;

      axios.get(params.uri).then((res)=>{
        const question = res.data;
        console.log(question);
        this.setState({ question });
      })

  }
```

This is JSON file where Object URI contains a JSON file so how to read

```
[
  {
       "id": 59413,
       "thumbnail": {
       "id": "60255",
       "title": "dornoch-castle-whisky-bar",
       "alt": "dornoch-castle-whisky-bar",
       "url": "https://media-magazine.trivago.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/23144800/dornoch-castle-whisky-bar.jpg",
      "courtesy": "",
      "position": "center"
    },
    "thumbnail_url": "https://media-magazine.trivago.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/23144800/dornoch-castle-whisky-bar.jpg",
    "slug": "dornoch-castle-scotland-whisky",
    "uri": "http://trivago-magazine-work-sample-server.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dornoch-castle-scotland-whisky.json",
    "title": "Dornoch Castle: A Whisky Tasting at One of the World's Most Popular Hotel Bars",
    "card_title": "Whisky Tasting at Dornoch Castle in the Scottish Highlands",
    "show_publish_date": false,
    "date": "January 29th, 2019",
    "newsletter_popup": false,
    "newsletter_popup_header_image": false,
    "taxonomies": {
      "destinations": [
        {
          "name": "Europe",
          "uri": "/destination/international/europe",
          "slug": "europe",
          "term_id": 1384
        }
      ],
      "themes": [],
      "types": [
        {
          "name": "Nature",
          "uri": "/type/nature",
          "slug": "nature",
          "term_id": 1380
        }
      ]
    },
    "excerpt": "Dornoch Castle has amassed a whisky collection unlike most any other in the world. trivago Magazine Editor, Joe Baur, signs up for their whisky tasting. Video below."
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, it's an array of objects. so `res.data[0]` would be the first element, `res.data[0]['uri']` would be the url of the json object. If you want to get that JSON from that URL, you'll just need to pass that value into axios to load the JSON.

`axios.get(res.data[0]['uri']).then((res)=>{...})`

Not sure on your use case, but that should give you access to the information in the `res` variable in the callback.